# Incrementing a number in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string: `0-3-terms` and I need to increment the 3 by 20 every time I click a button, also the start value might not always be 3 but I'll use it in this example..

I managed to do this using substring but it was so messy, I'd rather see if it's possible using Regex but I'm not good with Regex. So far I got here, I thought I would use the two hyphens to find the number I need to increment.

```
var str = '0-3-terms';
var patt = /0-[0-9]+-/;
var match = str.match(patt)[0];

//output ["0-3-"]
```

How can I increment the number 3 by 20 and insert it back in to the str, so I get:

`0-23-terms, 0-43-terms, 0-63-terms` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing a replacement. So use `.replace`.

```
var str = '0-3-terms';
var patt = /-(\d+)-/;
var result = str.replace(patt,function(_,n) {return "-"+(+n+20)+"-";});
```

Comment: Learned something. Didn't realize JS can use regex callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `.split` instead of regex, if you prefer. That would look like this:

```js
var str = '0-3-terms';
var split = str.split('-');
split[1] = +split[1] + 20;
var result = split.join('-');
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using regex. Simply store the value and create string when the button is called..

```
//first value
var value = 3;
var str = '0-3-terms';

//after clicking the button
value = value+20;
str = "0-" + value + "-terms"
```

Comment: Using regex gives the ability to find any number of digits as they increase with each click. Your answer doesn't show how you get the next value once it has incremented beyond 3

Comment: You can update the variable "value" by 20 everytime the button is clicked. The next value is that updated value.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that the start value might not always be 3, so a regex would catch all digits.